# Can two consecutive arrays of the same type be treated as one?

Tags: c++

Consider the follwing code:

```
struct S {
    int a[2] = {1, 1};
    int b[3] = {2, 2 ,2};
};

int main() {
    S s;

    for (auto *p = std::begin(s.a); p != std::end(s.a); p++)
        std::cout << *p  << std::endl;

    for (auto *p = std::begin(s.b); p != std::end(s.b); p++)
        std::cout << *p  << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Can I rewrite it (and still have the same result) like this?

```
struct S {
    int a[2] = {1, 1};
    int b[3] = {2, 2 ,2};
};

int main() {
    S s;

    for (auto *p = std::begin(s.a); p != std::end(s.b); p++)
        std::cout << *p  << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The `S` struct in this code is StandardLayout so there's guarantee that `b` has higher address than `a`. Is the second approach safe or there's some kind of UB?

What if `a` is just an `int` (not an array). Can I do the following?

```
    for (auto *p = &s.a; p != std::end(s.b); p++)
        std::cout << *p  << std::endl;
```

Comment: `b` has a higher address than `a` but there could be a gap between `a` and `b`. So your code may not work in practise as well as not be guaranteed by the standard for the obvious reasons.

Comment: @john if both arrays are of the same type there should not be any gap right?

Comment: No, the C++ standard does not guarantee that.

Comment: There is no way in C++ to use a pointer from one array to access an element in another array legally.

Comment: @NathanOliver not even when attribute packed is used?

Comment: @TonyTannous Not even then.  The standard only defines adding to a pointer, which is what array accessing is, to be defined only for the range of elements in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standard layout types, there is a [note](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#26):

> There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object inserted by an implementation, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment.

so there may be padding in between the members `a` and `b`.

Even if there's no padding, [`std::begin(b)`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.range#4) and [`std::end(a)`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.range#5) will simply return pointers to the underlying array. The result of comparing the pointers `a + 2` and `b` is [unspecified](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.eq-3.1). Also, simply computing `a + 3` is [undefined](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.compound#expr.add-4.3), so you can't do it the way you've tried with pointers.

To get the effect you want, you can write a custom iterator interface that internally manages pointers to different objects. Or you could just use the range-v3 library, like this:

```
for(auto i : ranges::views::concat(s.a, s.b))
    std::cout << i;
```

Comment: Even if there's no padding (can be checked with `static_assert`), treating `a` as `int[5]` is going to be UB.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat took a bit of digging, but clarified the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It may be done if you define custom iterator

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    class S {
    private:
        int a[2] = { 1, 2 };
        std::string someString;
        int b[3] = { 3, 4, 5 };
        int doNotInclude[3] = { 100, 101, 102 }; // let's do not include this array for our output loop for example
        int c[3] = { 6, 7, 8 };
    public:
        class iterator {
        private:
            int* curr;
            S* sOuter;
        public:
            iterator(S* Outer, int* р) :sOuter{ Outer }, curr(р) {}
            int& operator* () { return *curr; };
            bool operator==(const iterator& b) const { return curr == b.curr; };
            bool operator!=(const iterator& b) const { return curr != b.curr; }

            iterator& operator++() {
                if (std::end(this->sOuter->a) == curr + 1) {
                    curr = std::begin(this->sOuter->b);
                }
                else if (std::end(this->sOuter->b) == curr + 1) {
                    curr = std::begin(this->sOuter->c);
                }
                else {
                    ++curr;
                }
                return *this;
            }
        };
        iterator begin() { return iterator(this, std::begin(a)); };
        iterator end() { return iterator(this, std::end(c)); };
    };

    S s;
    for (auto& v : s) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```